# Let $S$ be the set of first 100 natural numbers,$L$ is the least common multiple of all the elements in $S,P$ is the product of all the primes in $S$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of first $100$ natural numbers,$L$ is the least common multiple of all the elements in $S,P$ is the product of all the primes in $S$ and $N$ is the natural number obtained by the ratio $L/P,$then
$(i)$find the number of cyphers at the end of $N$
$(ii)$find the number of divisors of $N$ which are even but not divisible by $4.$
$(iii)$find the sum of all the odd divisors of $N.$

---

I do not know how to find the lcm of first 100 natural numbers and how to find the value of $N.$So i cannot do much in this question.Its very tough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a start.

Note that the highest power of $2$ before $100$ is $2^6$. 
This means that the maximum power of $2$ in the LCM is $2^6$. You should be able to calculate the highest power for all primes under 100 in a similar fashion. When you're dividing $L$ by $P$, you're reducing the multiplicity of each factor by 1.

Get the prime factorisation for $N$ this way, and hopefully you'll know how to solve the problems you've mentioned.